# How to achieve anisotropic filtering on mipmapped texture?

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, mipmaps

I am loading a texture and using `glGenerateMipmap()` on it to achieve some level of mipmaping.

I get different result on nVidia gt 555m, and on Intel HD 3000.

Surprisingly the quality of the texture rendered on intel hd 3000 is much better than that of nVidia gt 555m.

The texture is slightly blurred when the program is run on nVidia. The quality of the texture looks much better when program is run from intel HD.

The tiling of the texture is much more apparent on nVidia!!
[image]

In the description of glGenerateMipmap() it is specified that the way glGenerateMipmap works is different for different implementations of OpenGL.

Is this something to do with glHint() GL_FASTEST , GL_NICEST , and GL_DONT_CARE?
Or am I better of mipmaping the texture myself?

Comment: You mean filter quality? No. If you want consistent behavior you should generate the mipmaps offline and use a format like DDS or KTX that is capable of storing the pre-filtered mipmaps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! that seems to be the option for now.

Comment: It seems it is something to do with the Anisotropic filtering. 
I have seen that setting in action in many games. 
I will look it up more!

Comment: Yes, I was just about to amend my comment with that. Graphics APIs are so lax with their requirements on texture filtering that quality varies wildly between implementations and drivers have quality settings that cannot be controlled by the application. One thing you can do is generate a false-colored texture with alternating solid red, solid green and solid blue images for each mipmap LOD. This will help you spot issues related to anisotropy / LOD selection by the driver. The concept is discussed in [greater detail here](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter28.html).

Comment: So, now the question is how to enable anisotropic filtering? `GLfloat max_aniso; glGetFloatv (GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, &max_aniso); glTexParameterf (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT, max_aniso);` should do the trick. As weird as this is going to sound, that parameter is floating-point. Implementations are free to figure out exactly what a number between say 15 and 16 actually means, because I sure cannot :P

Comment: that is weird, coz in games the filtering values are in multiples of 2.
btw, glTexParameterf worked like a charm. :)
Thanks a lot.!

Comment: I should mention here that today I commented out glTexParameterf in my code, and tried changing the setting in nvidia config. This seemed to have resulted in better texture rendering, kind of similar effect as using glTexParameterf().

Comment: True, but that forces everything to use anisotropic filtering. Most graphics engines are smart enough to enable it for textures that really need it and disable it for those that don't. It does not come free, it can increase the number of samples required to sample a texture significantly if you have a lot of geometry at extreme angles.